# Объект типа Path кидает исключение NullpointerException при попытке чтения

Tags: java, io

Дан метод в него приходит лист со значениями типа Path (файлы из директории , которые надо заархивировать ) При попытке прочесть его появляется исключение что такого файла не существует Вот эта строчка в коде -
try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(temp.toFile())))  В чем может быть причина ? В файл приходит лист с 1346 записями типа Path.

```
public static void packFiles(List<Path> sources, File target) {
        int count = 0;
        try (ZipOutputStream zip = new ZipOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(target)))) {
            while (sources.size() != count) {
             Path temp = sources.get(count++);
                ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(String.valueOf(temp));
                zip.putNextEntry(entry);
                try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(temp.toFile()))) {  **ЭТО МЕСТО !**
                    zip.write(bis.readAllBytes());
                }
                zip.closeEntry();
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Зачем переделали на `Path`? [В прошлый раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1247200/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-listfile-list-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%85%d0%b8%d0%b2-zip) что-то не заработало?

Comment: А так, приведите, пожалуйста, полную информацию об ошибке: тип ошибки, сообщение (буквально, а не своими словами), трассировку стека. Еще определите файл на котором возникает ошибка, проверьте есть ли он.

Comment: Сказали лучше использовать Path . Тот код запускал , тоже была ошибка. java.io.FileNotFoundException: COMMIT_EDITMSG (Не удается найти указанный файл)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:212)
 at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:154)
 at ru.job4j.io.Zip.packFiles(Zip.java:19)
 at ru.job4j.io.Zip.main(Zip.java:38)
он читает первый файл из списка и когда он пытается записать его выходит такая ошибка не нашел указанный файл

Comment: Внесите эту информацию в вопрос. Выведите в консоль полный путь к файлу (`temp.toFile().getAbsolutePath()`) и проверьте, есть ли он там

Comment: пишет , что не удается найти такой файл

Comment: Если просто вывести (`temp.toAbsolutePath()`)?

Comment: все также та же ошибка , просто я не пойму зачем ему путь если он просто создает архив из листа ?

Comment: Что значит «та же ошибка»? Если написать `System.out.println(temp.toAbsolutePath())` какой путь выводится? Есть ли там файл?

Comment: C:\projects\job4j_design\COMMIT_EDITMSG если я правильно понимаю все это путь к файлу ?  т.е все правильно ?

Comment: Этот файл существует?

Comment: Странно он почему то есть в листе приходящем , а в реале в этой директории его не поиск не находит , Откуда он появился ?

Comment: Получается что проблема в коде, который составляет приходящий список. Нужно разбираться с ним. В вопросе этого кода нет, поэтому ничего сказать про него не могу.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки ! А то я уже не знал , что тут не так

Comment: Да, пожалуйста! Кстати, не забывайте отмечать ответы, которые решили Вашу проблему как принятые. Слева от ответа есть для этого серая галочка.

Comment: Все решил задачу)спасибо еще раз!

Comment: Поздравляю! :-)

Answer (score 0):

используйте `Files.walk`, если вам файлы нужны.

Comment: Спасибо я его уже использую в методе , который возвращает отфильтрованный список